# Table in PHP from DB only showing 61 entries?

Tags: php, sql, database, html-table

Trying to display a table with 150+ entries and only 61 are displaying, how would I make all entries display indefinitely on the page or add a "pages" feature so we can browse all entries, not just up to 61 of them?

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">Posting Info</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Post Info Table
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row-sm-4">
                    <div class="col-lg-6" style="width: 100% !important;">
                        <form role="form" style="width: 100% !important;">
                              <div class="table-responsive" style="width: 100% !important;">
                                 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width: 100% !important;">
                                     <thead>
                                         <tr>
                                             <th>Example1</th>
                                             <th>Example2</th>
                                             <th>Example3</th>
                                             <th>Example4</th>
                                             <th>Example5</th>
                                             <th>Example6</th>
                                             <th>Example7</th>
                                             <th>Example8</th>
                                         </tr>
                                     </thead>
                                     <tbody>
                                           <?php
                                                $postList = '';
                                                $q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `examples`");
                                                $q->execute();
                                                $q = $q->fetchAll();

                                                foreach ($q as $post)
                                                {
                                                      $postList .= '<tr> <td>'.$post['exmpl1'].'</td>
                                                                                  <td>'.$post['exmpl2'].'</td>
                                                                                  <td>'.$post['exmpl3'].'</td>
                                                                                  <td><a href="../'.$post['exmpl4'].'">Click to View</a></td>
                                                                                  <td>'.$post['exmpl5'].'</td>
                                                                                  <td>'.$post['exmpl6'].'</td>
                                                                                  <td>'.$post['exmpl7'].'</td>
                                                                                  <td>'.$post['exmpl8'].'</td>
                                                      </tr>';
                                                }

                                                print $postList;
                                          ?>
                                     </tbody>
                                 </table>
                             </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently only displays up to 61 entries but all information in the entries are displaying correctly. The code works, but seems to be limited. I am looking for a way to remove this limit.

Comment: Add more records to examples table :)

Comment: There are 137 records in the database, but only 61 are being put into this table. That's the issue :(

Comment: find the length of array $q , so you should find exact how many value return by query

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine and it *should* display all the matching rows.

You should debug it by using `echo 'There are ' . $q->rowCount() . ' rows found.';`, This will output how many rows were found.

As for the pages feature, it's called a [pagination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination) and you should look up how to make one.

Comment: Might sound stupid but where would I put your echo test string? I've placed it several places and it does nothing :/

Comment: Just after </table> Insert the following <?= echo 'There are ' . $q->rowCount() . ' rows found.'; ?>

Comment: Put it at that location and it didn't do anything
Also, had to change it to "print" instead of "echo"

Comment: Are you not getting any errors at all? Print/echo shouldn't be necessary here. Try changing it to `<?= '<script>alert("' . $q->rowCount() . ' rows");</script>'; ?>` You should get a JavaScript alert.

Comment: it says "says 1 rows" yet 61 are being displayed

Comment: Very odd. Can you try placing the same debugging code just after `$q->execute();` and see what it tells you?

Comment: gives HTTP ERROR 500 :/

Answer (score 0):

add `LIMIT 200` in your select query.

Comment: Added it in, now it displays 35 entries in the table. Very confused?

Answer (score -2):

$q=mysql_query("select * from students limit 61");

$num_row = mysql_num_row($q);

You can use like this

Comment: I don't ONLY want it to show 61, it is ONLY showing 61 and no more. I am trying to allow it to show all entries